# Fly in a question

Tags: questions

I'm just wondering if it's okay to ask someone where is he flying to this way:

> Where do you fly to?

I asked someone what's his destination using this question and I think I've asked it wrong.

Comment: It's fine in a situation like this: Person A: I'm going to Ireland next week by plane. Person B: Where do you fly to? Person A: Belfast.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Even in that context, I think *Where **are you flying** to?* would be far more likely (reflecting ***am going***, rather than the somewhat starchy *I **go** to Ireland*). The only obvious context where the ***do + infinitive*** form would be ***expected*** is with a *habitual / repeated* action, as in  *A: I fly to Ireland **every week** by plane. B: Where do you fly to?*

Comment: @Fumblefingers (short form of name) - Matter of opinion. Present tense is OK for a scheduled or planned event.

Comment: God forbid that I should ever be 'starchy'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I'm not saying the "do-support" version isn't "acceptable" for the exact cited context - just that imho it's only *marginally* so. Consider a very closely related context: *A: I'm going to London tonight.* Where B could definitely (albeit *slightly* formally) ask *When do you leave?* rather than *When are you leaving?* But how to explain to a nns that *What time train do you catch?* is "dated / starchy / weird" compared to *What time train are you catching?* Safest to just advise using auxiliary [TO BE] + continuous verb, rather than invoking do-support.

Comment: You might still say 'Does your train go to Waterloo or Victoria?"